# gstreamer, how to ignore errors on h264 rtsp stream and keep recording

Tags: gstreamer, h.264, rtsp, recording

I have a gstreamer pipeline where I get a rtsp stream from a mobile app and I both save it to a file and send to a virtual v4l2loopback device.

The pipeline is this:

> gst-launch-1.0 -e rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.2.101:8080/video/h264 latency=100 ! queue ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! tee name=t t. ! queue ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video2 t. ! queue ! mp4mux ! filesink location=out.mp4

It works great but sometimes the recording hangs with the error **Buffer has no PTS.**
I think that probably sometimes the app is sending duplicated frames or similar. For me is not a problem if the recording has some glitches but with the error above I lose it completely.

Is there a way to avoid this with some "cleaner" component, if it exists, on the pipeline? Or is there an alternative to avoid this?